# Adding a number to an array, checking whether or not the number is already in the array, and looping the check

Tags: vb.net

I have a basic program to hold a hypothetical election for a school council. Before the student votes, I need them to enter their 'voter number'; this is to make sure each student only votes once. I want to store these numbers in an array, and check this array when a student enters their number. This is my entire program:
'''Module Module1

```
Sub Main()

    Dim tutorgroups() As String = {"7a", "7b", "7c", "7d", "7e", "7f", "8a", "8b", "8c", "8d", "8e", "8f", "9a", "9b", "9c", "9d", "9e", "9f", "10a", "10b", "10c", "10d", "10e", "10f"} 'tutor groups array
    Dim tutor As String 'selected tutor group
    Dim number As Integer 'number of students in each group 
    Dim candidates As Integer 'amount of candidates


    'choosing tutor group
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of your tutor group:")
    tutor = Console.ReadLine()

    'checking a tutor group exists
    While tutorgroups.Contains(tutor) = False
        Console.WriteLine("Not an existing tutor group. Enter the name of your tutor group:")
        tutor = Console.ReadLine()
    End While

    'entering the number of students in a tutor group
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of students in " & tutor)
    number = Console.ReadLine()
    ' If number > 35 Or number < 28 Then 'range check making sure there are at least 28 students and no more than 35 
    ' Console.WriteLine("The amount of students in a tutor group must be between 28 and 35. Re enter the amount of students in " & tutor)
    '  number = Console.ReadLine()
    '  End If

    'entering the number of candidates in the tutor group
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of candidates in " & tutor)
    candidates = Console.ReadLine()
    If candidates > 4 Or candidates < 1 Then 'range check making sure there is at least 1 candidate and no more than 4 candidates
        Console.WriteLine("There has to be at least 1, and at most 4 candidates")
    End If

    'names of candidates
    Dim CandidateNames(candidates) As String 'array storing the candidates' names
    Dim x As Integer

    'entering the names of each candidate so students can vote for them.
    For x = 1 To candidates
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a candidates name:")
        CandidateNames(x) = Console.ReadLine()
    Next
    For x = 1 To candidates
        Console.WriteLine(CandidateNames(x) & " is candidate " & x)
    Next

    'each student's vote
    Dim entry As String

    'vote count for each student.
    Dim votes1 As Integer = 0
    Dim votes2 As Integer = 0
    Dim votes3 As Integer = 0
    Dim votes4 As Integer = 0

    'count for the number of students not voting
    Dim novotes As Integer = 0

    'dimentions used for making sure each students only votes once
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim voternum() As String = {}
    Dim voternumentry As String

    'actual student voting. each student enters the name if the student they're voting for.
    For i = 0 To number - 1
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your voter number:")
        voternumentry = Console.ReadLine()
        voternum(i) = voternumentry
        While voternum(i).Contains(voternumentry)
            Console.WriteLine("enter a different number that hasnt already been used:")
            voternumentry = Console.ReadLine()
            voternum(35) = voternumentry
        End While

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of the student you're voting for (type 0 to abstain):")
        entry = Console.ReadLine()
        If entry = 1 Then
            votes1 = votes1 + 1
        ElseIf entry = 2 Then
            votes2 = votes2 + 1
        ElseIf entry = 3 Then
            votes3 = votes3 + 1
        ElseIf entry = 4 Then
            votes4 = votes4 + 1
        ElseIf entry = "0" Then
            novotes = novotes + 1
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Not a valid candidate number. Enter the number of the student you're voting for (type 0 to abstain):")
            entry = Console.ReadLine()
        End If
    Next

    'voting statistics
    Dim totalvotes As Integer
    Dim votepercentage1 As Integer
    Dim votepercentage2 As Integer
    Dim votepercentage3 As Integer
    Dim votepercentage4 As Integer

    'calculating the percentage of votes each candidate earned
    totalvotes = number - novotes
    votepercentage1 = votes1 / totalvotes * 100
    votepercentage2 = votes2 / totalvotes * 100
    votepercentage3 = votes3 / totalvotes * 100
    votepercentage4 = votes4 / totalvotes * 100

    'voting results
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine(CandidateNames(1) & " got " & votes1 & " votes, and " & votepercentage1 & "% of the votes ")
    Console.WriteLine(CandidateNames(2) & " got " & votes2 & " votes, and " & votepercentage2 & "% of the votes ")
    Console.WriteLine(CandidateNames(3) & " got " & votes3 & " votes, and " & votepercentage3 & "% of the votes ")
    Console.WriteLine("And " & CandidateNames(4) & " got " & votes4 & " votes, and " & votepercentage4 & "% of the votes ")
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine(novotes & " students in " & tutor & " didn't vote")
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine("There were " & totalvotes & " cast, and " & novotes & " people didnt vote")

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
```

And this is the specific piece of code I am having issues with:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter your voter number:")
        voternumentry = Console.ReadLine()
        voternum(i) = voternumentry
        While voternum(i).Contains(voternumentry)
            Console.WriteLine("enter a different number that hasn't already been used:")
            voternumentry = Console.ReadLine()
            voternum(35) = voternumentry
        End While
```

I emailed my teacher for help but she hasn't got back to me yet. I've had no luck on Reddit, and no one else in my class has got this far.

Any help would be great as we have having an assessment on this to go towards our finals GCSE grade in computer science.

Thanks internet

Answer (score 0):

It would be very similar to your existing code that checks the tutor groups:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your voter number:")
voternumentry = Console.ReadLine()
While voternum.Contains(voternumentry)
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a different number that hasn't already been used:")
    voternumentry = Console.ReadLine()
End While
voternum(i) = voternumentry
```

The key here is that you don't add the voter number to the array until AFTER you've verified it's not already there.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I’m not home at the moment but I’ll try your code as soon as I’m home.

Answer (score 0):

One of the fundamentals of software development is to pick the right data structure for the job.

In this case, the job is: keep track of a number of items, ensuring uniqueness.  An array is not the best choice here.  There is one particular type of data structure that is designed for this use case.  I would suggest that you do some background reading on sets.

There are two different generic sets offered by the .NET Framework, depending on details of usage.  One is `HashSet(Of T)`, the other is `SortedSet(Of T)`.  `HashSet` does not keep any particular ordering, and is optimized for fast access (O(1)).  `SortedSet` will put the items in order according to how the items compare, and has somewhat slower access (O(log(n) if I remember correctly).

Disregard this suggestion if the assignment requires you to use arrays, perhaps as a building block to discussing more advanced data structures (like sets) later.

Comment: We were told we’ve been taught everything we need to know across the last 2 school years to complete the task, but if we wanted to we could use stuff we’ve learned outside of lessons. I’ll stick to what I know for now but I’ll come back to this if I need to. Thanks!